# What is the Android equivalent of Xamarin's View.GestureRecognizers Property?

Tags: android, xamarin, sdk

When using Xamarin (for Android application), it is possible to add to a view a GestureRecognizer. This recogniser listens to tap events for example, and decodes them, passing the event to a callback method. Only views with a gesture recogniser will pass the onTouchEvent to the Android OS.

In Xamarin it is possible to get view.gesturesRecognizers().

Is there a way in Android to recognise that this view has a gesture detector?

```
            <StackLayout Padding="10, 0"
                         BackgroundColor='Red'
                         x:Name="_layout1">
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer 
                            Tapped="OnButtonTapped" 
                            NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer 
                            Tapped="DoubleTapGestureRecognizerTapped" 
                            NumberOfTapsRequired="2"/>

                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <Button Text="{Binding FingerprintButtonText}" Clicked="Fingerprint_Clicked"
                        IsVisible="{Binding FingerprintLock}"></Button>
                <Button Text="{u:I18n LogOut}" Clicked="LogOut_Clicked"></Button>
                <Label Text="This StackLayout has a tap gesture listener on it. It's the red area that is clickable." />
                <Image  Source="yubikey.png" >
                </Image>
            </StackLayout>
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector

Comment: I have an Android SDK that runs in a Xamarin app. I need to be able to distinguish in the SDK between views that have gestureRecognizers and views that do not.
In other words, i'd like to know in the Android SDK if a view is "gesturable".

Comment: There seems to be no property equivalent to GestureRecognizers. Each view can add a gesture.